# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Error The provided uri did not return any Service Endpoints

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, asmx

A running custom application that talk to Microsoft Dynamics CRM via the SDK,  last two days it encountered this error 
The provided uri did not return any Service Endpoints!

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Data[0] = "The provided uri did not return any Service Endpoints! {0}" Data[1] = "" at 
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1..ctor(Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary) at 
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration..ctor(Uri serviceUri) at 
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration[TService](Uri serviceUri) at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1..ctor(Uri uri, Uri
 homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials clientCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials) at RMSystem.MyService.SaveAdditionalRef(clsRegistration reg, ResultSet& 
 ResultSet, String id) in E:\EzeMoney13Aug2013\EzeMoney12Aug2013_IIS_Live\EZE_Money_App_Live\RMSystem\RMSystem\MyService.asmx.cs:line 554 at 
 RMSystem.AddReference.Save() in E:\EzeMoney13Aug2013\EzeMoney12Aug2013_IIS_Live\EZE_Money_App_Live\RMSystem\RMSystem\AddReference.aspx.cs:line 111
```

To fix this, try to recycle the CRMAppPool and run your custom application again but still getting the same

Comment: Can you share some more details about system? Is it an Internet-Facing-Deployment using Claim-Based authentication?

Comment: Hi Filburt,  Actually I am new on dynamics-crm. My vendor(Development agency) is not responding. Code is published and deployed at our local server. Please share your Skype id I will show you my machine.

Answer (score 2):

I received this error when attempting to connect to Dynamics using a connection string with AuthType=ClientSecret. Previously I was connecting successfully using username and password with a connection string of the form

```
"Url={dynamicsConnectionString};Username={username};Password={password};AuthType=Office365;"
```

The connection string was changed to have the form

```
"AuthType=ClientSecret;RequireNewInstance=false;Url={CrmDynamicsPrivatePrimaryConnection};ClientId={CrmDynamicsPrivateClientId};ClientSecret={CrmDynamicsPrivateClientSecret};LoginPrompt=Never;"
```

The error occurred because I was using an outdated version of Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly. I was using version 9.0.2.27, and according to a web report, version 9.1.0.13 is needed for connecting with ClientSecret. I updated to version 9.1.0.68 using NuGet, and the Dynamics connection worked.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the CRM async service on the server resolved this for me.

[image]